# Möbius: Find the general form

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation, fixed-points

I am studying about supplementary questions of the theory of linear transformations. A bilinear transformation with one fixed point is said to be parabolic. Please, can you help me to solve this problem:

"Find the general form of the parabolic transformation of the disk $|z|<R$ into itself if the point R is fixed"

Comment: To find fixed points, solve $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} = z$. If the discriminant of the quadratic is zero it is said be parabolic. You will get both roots equal to $\frac{a-d}{2c}$ and this should equal $R$ in your case.

Comment: Let $R = 1$. $f(z) = 1/(z - 1)$ maps $\widehat {\mathbb R}$ to itself, therefore maps the unit circle to a line $l$ which is orthogonal to $\mathbb R$. Next, $g(z) = z + a i$ with $a \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ maps $l$ to itself and has exactly one fixed point. Show that the general form of the desired transform is $f^{-1} \circ g \circ f$.

Comment: @Maxim thank you very much, but I think that in this case, we can choose $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z-R}$? I have just only known that the answer to this problem is transformation $w(z)=\dfrac{(R-ki)z-R^2}{z-(R+ki)}$, where $k$ is a real number, $k\ne 0$ (if $k=\infty$, then $w(z)=z$), but I don't know how do!